# Etiquette for editing info from comment into question

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I just had [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1601742) rejected and would like to check on the general etiquette of this situation.

After some back-and-forth in the comments, OP for this question responded in a comment with some additional info resulting from our suggestions. I felt that this new info would help others to answer, and so edited it into the question verbatim and put my comment as "incorporated additional info from comment into Q". My edit was rejected as changing the "original meaning or intent of the post".

What should I have done instead? Just prompted the OP to do it themselves? (I have done this in the interim). Is it generally not acceptable to update someone's question to include new details of the problem, even if they themselves were the ones to provide these details?

Comment: You should put inside your message that was an OP comment you want to re-introduce inside the question. We don't really know here if it's a  request from OP or on your own.

Comment: @j0k he did mention this.

Comment: I suppose my message wasn't completely unambiguous about the fact that I was adding a comment **from the OP** into the Q. So if I had made that clearer, the edit would probably have been ok do you think?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "*incorporated additional info from comment into Q*" I don't find any mention that the comment is from OP. It could be a discution between two people not included OP.

Comment: @j20 I think, I put a better attention when people mention OP, such like introduce information from a comment. Otherwise, it is not very clear.

Comment: Anyway, such edits are much better be done by the OP himself so first ask him to do that and only if he ignore this make such edit yourself.

Comment: @j0k is the onus on the diligent review check the comments? If someone claims it's from the OP you'd surely check? (I agree it could be clearer.)

Comment: Ok, in future I'll prompt OP first, but failing that make it much clearer whose info I am adding to the Q. Thanks all

Comment: @hayden if the message says that it comes from a discussion inside comments with OP, I usually open the question in a new tab to check comments, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have incorporated your edit into the question.

Your edit is totally acceptable, since it is coming from OP in the comment. There are cases where code is pasted in the comment, and the whole thing garbled up that it is not possible to guess what the original text is, but this is not the case here.

If I were to review the edit, I would approve it.

*Personally*, I don't make such edit immediately, except for the case where the clarification in the comment affects the direction of the answers. I would ask the OP to edit the question themselves if there are not many people rushing in to blindly make a shot at answering.